# flask_sqlalchemy TypeError on count()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In the chinook.sqlite db, the two tables below are related.

> artists

- ArtistId(PK)
- Name

> albums

- AlbumId(PK)
- Title
- Artistid(FK))

I am getting the db metadata reflected by

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)
```

In my model.py

```
from app import db

class Album(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['albums']
    artist = db.relationship('Artist' , backref = 'artists')

class Artist(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['artists']
    album = db.relationship('Album', backref = 'albums')
```

In the View,

> {{ artist.album.count() }}

Gives error,
***TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)***

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Query.all()` returns a `list`, so `...all().count()` will just result in the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORM relationships have not been [configured to be dynamic](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship), so instead of `Query.count()` you're calling `list.count()`. Use `len()`:

```
{{ len(artist.albums) }}
```

Your model definitions also define extra relationship properties. Instead of `backref`, which is a shorthand for creating a new relationship property on the other end, use `back_populates` to link the 2 sides together:

```
class Album(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['albums']
    artist = db.relationship('Artist', back_populates = 'albums')

class Artist(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['artists']
    albums = db.relationship('Album', back_populates = 'artist')
```